# SSIS Fuzzy look up not loading tables to match

Tags: ssis, fuzzy-logic, fuzzy-comparison

[image: Image of the issue I am seeing]

I am running into an issue with the FuzzyLookup function of SSIS.

When I try to load in the data from either an Excel file or via two SQL tables I am unable to get the tables to load to complete the matching steps.

Has anyone else run into this issue?

Comment: What type of connection are you using for the reference table?

Comment: I am using ADO Net

Comment: The reference table must use an OLE DB connection.

Comment: I have also tried OLE DB Source

Comment: Is this connection for the reference table (not input component)?  And you're connecting to SQL Server, right?

Comment: right this is the mapping for the fuzzy look up. The import data source is from one SQL table and the items that are being compared to the import data is another table.

Comment: I was able to resolve this issue. Found that the issue was the data format in the tables. Rebuild the databases and table and this resolved the issue.